# Record persisting past test in Rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm working through the railstutorial.org site and seem to have a problem with an integration test. It's suppose to check if a user gets properly created after a form post which works but, on subsequent tests fails because the test db is not getting rolled backed, this causes error because of validating that users can't have same email. Any explanation why the record would persist? If relevant the code in question is from [this](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-up#code%3asignup_success_test) listing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Note:* I am the author of the [Rails Tutorial](http://railstutorial.org/). The `config.cache_classes = false` line got added after Peter Cooper [reported](http://www.rubyinside.com/how-to-rails-3-and-rspec-2-4336.html) that it was necessary to get RSpec and Spork to work together on his system. Since I have not found it necessary, and since it seemed to introduce lots of problems (such as those identified in this thread), that line has since been removed. If you use [the latest version of the book](http://railstutorial.org/book) you shouldn't run into this problem.

Comment: The tutorial seemed to state using spork was optional.  Don't know if it matters, but I chose to not use spork as I thought it would simplify things.  RSpec and autotest would yield results in 0-3 seconds on my macbook pro, which always seemed fast enough for me.  I figured I'd look into spork once I wrote something large enough to warrant optimizing the development cycle.  Perhaps that makes me a 'minority configuration' user.  Not sure if it explains my having encounted a bump in the road here http://stackoverflow.com/q/5308307/657003

Comment: This is exactly what I ended up doing since it was the only difference I had from what was in your repo, though I wonder whats with all the strangeness about changing this setting

Answer (score 0):

Look into using [database_cleaner](https://github.com/bmabey/database_cleaner). Your spec helper will contain something like this:

```
config.before(:suite) do
  DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
  DatabaseCleaner.clean_with :truncation       
end

config.before(:each) do
  ActionMailer::Base.deliveries = []
  DatabaseCleaner.start
end

config.after(:each) do 
  DatabaseCleaner.clean
end

config.after(:all) do
  DatabaseCleaner.clean_with :truncation
end
```

Comment: RSpec is already suppose to be running everything in transactions so I was more confused as to why its not working to being with

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the issue was with the line

```
config.cache_classes = false
```

I had set this to false assuming it would make sure not to use stale class data, but it seems to be having the opposite effect among other things. Changing this to true fixed all the weirdness I was having, but I am still on confused as to why. I think it may have something to do with the OS as in the tutorial it was said that for OSX (which I am running) having that line set to true works fine, while other OSes need it set false

Comment: That line is part of the test.rb file in config/environments

Answer (score 0):

While Hartl's tutorial struck me as flawless, perhaps the issue you raise here can be classified as an important ommission.

This here: [RailsTutorial - chapter 8.4.3 - Test database not clearing after adding user in integration test](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5454373/657003)
and
This here: [Rails 3 Tutorial Chapter 11 "Validation failed: Email has already been taken" error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5308307/657003)
and
This here: [config.cache_classes = false messing up rspec tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5272978/657003)

... are all variations on the same problem.

Mike Hartl, if you are out there, you seem a mere one issue away from RoR Tutorial perfection.

Best regards,

Perry