# Rails 3 + Rspec 2: Validation failed: Email has already been taken

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec2, factory-bot, rspec-rails

I have 2 models, `User` and `Bucket`. `User` `has_many` `Buckets` and a `Bucket` `belongs_to` a `User`.

In `factories.rb`, I have:

```
Factory.define :user do |user|
  user.email  "teste@test.com"
  user.password               "foobar"
  user.password_confirmation  "foobar"
end


Factory.sequence :email do |n| 
  "person-#{n}@example.com"
end

Factory.define :bucket do |bucket|
  bucket.email        "user@example.com"
  bucket.confirmation false
  bucket.association :user
end
```

and I have a login_user module as follows:

```
def login_user
    before(:each) do
      @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
      @user = Factory.create(:user)
      #@user.confirm!
      sign_in @user
    end
  end
```

I am using Spork and Watch and my `Buckets_controller_spec.rb` is as simple as:

```
describe "User authenticated: " do

   login_user  

   @bucket = Factory(:bucket)

   it "should get index" do
     get 'index'
     response.should be_success
   end
...
end
```

The error is always the same:

```
Failures:

  1) BucketsController User authenticated: should get index
     Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
     ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
       Validation failed: Email has already been taken
     # ./lib/controller_macros.rb:12:in `block in login_user'
```

And it only happens when I have the `Factory(:bucket)`. The login works fine when I don't add the `Factory(:bucket)`.

It's always the same error. I have tried adding `:email => Factory.next(:email)` to the user, but no success.

Edit:

In `rails c test`:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :019 > bucket = Factory(:bucket, :email => "hello@hello.com")
    ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Email has already been taken

    ruby-1.9.2-p180 :018 >   Bucket.create(:email => "hello@hello.com")
     => #<Bucket id: 2, email: "hello@hello.com", confirmation: nil, created_at: "2011-04-08 21:59:12", updated_at: "2011-04-08 21:59:12", user_id: nil>
```

Edit 2:

I found out that the error is in the association, however, I don't know how to fix it.

```
  bucket.association :user
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you define a factory with an association you need to give the factory an object to associate with whenever you use the factory.

This should work:

```
describe "User authenticated: " do
  login_user
  @bucket = Factory(:bucket, :user => @user)

  it "should get index" do
    get 'index'
    response.should be_success
  end
end
```

That way factorygirl knows to make a bucket which is associated with @user.

Answer (score 5):

Try this in your user factory:

```
Factory.define :user do |f|
  f.sequence(:email) { |n| "test#{n}@example.com" }
  ...
end
```

I think that's probably your problem. When you use `f.email = "anyvalue"` it's going to use that value every time. I see you were trying to create a sequence in the next block, but I'm not sure that sequence is getting used.

ALSO - be aware that if you get tests interrupted by a crash or something, sometimes bogus test data can get left in your test DB instead of being rolled back.

Very first thing I try if something worked once and then quit working is to reset the test db.

```
rake db:test:prepare
```

That will clean everything out.

If this doesn't work let me know and I'll take a second look!

Comment: thank you. I've tried all that with no success. However, I believe I found the problem but I'm not sure if this makes sense. Here it goes: When I'm creating a bucket (which is associated to a user) I'm not passing the user, so if I do Factory(:bucket, :user => User.first), it will work. Makes sense?

Comment: Yeah, that would make sense. I have had associations like this where I must create a valid association in order for the other model to be tested.

Answer (score 0):

If someone is getting this recently with your views. Try using [Database Cleaner](https://github.com/bmabey/database_cleaner).

For more info: [RailsTutorial - chapter 8.4.3 - Test database not clearing after adding user in integration test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5454373/railstutorial-chapter-8-4-3-test-database-not-clearing-after-adding-user-in)