# ROR 3 Michael Hartl tutorial - assign Admin role invalidates the user

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am experiencing an issue as I am following Michael Hartl's tutorial and currently at the [end of Chapter 10](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/updating-showing-and-deleting-users#sec%3aadministrative_users).

When I use `toggle` in the rails console to flip the admin property of a user from `false` to `true` (I'm trying to create an Admin user), I am successful in doing so; however that user becomes invalid - when I try to log in to the application with this user's credential I am getting an error that the credentials are incorrect (even though they are)

Just from checking the logs and the looking at the terminal, it seems the authenticity token is either missing or incorrect - any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

I tried following the tutorial as close as possible, I doubt I missed something, but its obviously possible.

Comment: It is quite difficult to understand all your situation  written in prose. Show errors and code maybe? )

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar problem as well.  It appears (and perhaps someone else can explain why) that when you run `user.toggle!(:admin)`, it resets the password to ''.  To fix it I just ran `user.update_attributes(:password => "yourpassword", :password_confirmation => 'yourpassword` in the console.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work, but I still don't understand how it comes about and whether its by design or not. But, I did manage to register an Admin user, my mistake was that I didn't set the password field in the console before calling `user.toggle!(:admin)`.
i.e.

```
u = User.find_by_id(1)
u.password = "password"
u.toggle!(:admin)
```

and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  I too stumbled here.  Part of what made this puzzling to me as a newcomer to rails was that the error was in my understanding of how the testing sqlite db is handled, not the code that was written.  I thought I was guaranteed a fresh start (new copy of project_root/db/test.sqlite3)  each time testing began, but this is not always the case.  More here:

[Rails 3 Tutorial Chapter 11 "Validation failed: Email has already been taken" error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5308307/657003)

and here:

[RailsTutorial - chapter 8.4.3 - Test database not clearing after adding user in integration test](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5454373/657003)

and here:

http://rubygems.org/gems/database_cleaner (click on 'Documentation')

Most of these discussions surrounds the testing db, but the exchange also clued me in to the existence of development and production databases as well.  Look at your directory listing for project_root/db for your ah-ha! moment.

hth,

Perry